# Increase Audio over Display Port cable

Tags: audio, display, displayport

So i just plugged my new Display port cable to my PC and i was fascinated to discover that the Display Port functions much like a HDMI cable, it carries both audio and video signal.I plugged in my headphone jack into my PC, and didn't get a sound on it. So i didn't first realize it and thought the sound driver had a problem but on checking with the windows sound driver, it points to my monitor model as the target hardware for audio signal `Lenovo l2551 wide`. So i went ahead and plugged in my headphone jack into the monitor and got the sound, but the Audio Volume is so small compared to what i get directly from PC.Can i increase the volume of the Audio Signal coming out of the monitor?

Comment: Have you tried your Windows volume slider? Alternatively check in the on screen menu system for your monitor.

Comment: Yes but the maximum volume is way below the maximum i get from the in built one, lemme try looking for a monitor option